# Cypress.io code coverage publish to azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, cypress, code-coverage, istanbul

I am able to generate code coverage via cypress.io using a combination of Istanbul and cypress/code-coverage. This generates a coverage folder and I can view the report in an HTML format present in index.html.
I am unable to use this file to publish code coverage when running it as CI in azure devops. Has anyone found a way or has the experience to publish this as a JaCoCo or Cobertura code coverage report so it appears in the code coverage tab?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify [custom reporters](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage#custom-reporters) inside your `package.json`. This should do it in your case to get a `Cobertura` report:

*package.json*

```json
"dependencies": {
  ...
},
"nyc": {
  "reporter": [
    "cobertura"
  ]
}
```

A full list of alternative reporters can be found [here](https://istanbul.js.org/docs/advanced/alternative-reporters/).